# Android: how to load a db file on server?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I am developing an application where users can upload their own recipes. So, I want to create and put a sqlite .db file on my server and modify the database when users upload their recipes. Is this even possible? Instead, it seems that there is a way to connect an Android application to MySQL, but some people say it is not recommended to use MySQL in android.

Comment: you can upload text via http or using any service like rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to create a web service to communicate with your app. There are many ways to do this. Here are a few good tutorials that might help you.

http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/connect-android-to-mysql-database-tutorial.8339/

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/android-mysql-client.html

Use SQLite for data stored on the Android device, and whatever DB you think is appropriate on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your application. If it's a small, use Mongo db in the server side. And upload JSON Format to your server. It will save into mongo directly.

Answer (score 1):

I the best way to do that is through json format the link is the tutorial 
www.androidhive.info